# gitlab ci/cd conditional 'when: manual'?

Tags: gitlab, terraform, cicd

Is it possible to for a gitlab ci/cd job to be triggered manually only under certain conditions that are evaluated based on the output of jobs earlier in the pipeline? I would like my 'terraform apply' job to run automatically if my infrastructure hasn't changed, or ideally to be skipped entirely, but to be triggered manually if it has.

My .tf file is below. I'm using OPA to set an environment variable to true or false when my infrastructure changes but as far as I can tell, I can only include or exclude jobs when the pipeline is set up, based on e.g. git branch information, not at pipeline run time.

Thanks!

```
default:
  image:
    name: hashicorp/terraform:light
    entrypoint:
      - '/usr/bin/env'
  before_script:
    - echo ${AWS_PROFILE}
    - echo ${TF_ROOT}

plan:
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - terraform init
    - terraform plan -var "profile=${AWS_PROFILE}" -out tfplan.binary
    - terraform show -json tfplan.binary > tfplan.json
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ${TF_ROOT}/.terraform
      - ${TF_ROOT}/.terraform.lock.hcl
      - ${TF_ROOT}/tfplan.binary
      - ${TF_ROOT}/tfplan.json

validate:
  image:
    name: openpolicyagent/opa:latest-debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - /opa eval --format pretty --data ../../policy/terraform.rego --input tfplan.json "data.policy.denied"
    - AUTHORISED=`/opa eval --format raw --data ../../policy/terraform.rego --input tfplan.json "data.policy.authorised"`
    - echo INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGED=`/opa eval --format raw --data ../../policy/terraform_infrastructure_changed.rego --input tfplan.json "data.policy.changed"` >> validate.env
    - cat validate.env
    - if [ $AUTHORISED == 'false' ]; then exit 1; else exit 0; fi
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ${TF_ROOT}/.terraform
      - ${TF_ROOT}/.terraform.lock.hcl
      - ${TF_ROOT}/tfplan.binary
    reports:
      dotenv: ${TF_ROOT}/validate.env
  needs: ["plan"]

apply:
  script:
    - echo ${INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGED}
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - terraform apply tfplan.binary
  artifacts:
      paths:
        - ${TF_ROOT}/.terraform
        - ${TF_ROOT}/.terraform.lock.hcl
        - ${TF_ROOT}/tfplan.binary
  needs:
    - job: validate
      artifacts: true
  when: manual
  rules:
    - allow_failure: false
```

Comment: Side question...

I get it why you want to manually trigger `terraform apply` on infrastructure changes, but...   Why bother triggering `terraform apply` if infrastructure doesn't change? It would not have any effect.

Comment: @ravenwing: I'd be happy to skip the whole job, without triggering apply, but I couldn't work out how to do that at run time either. Sorry that I didn't phrase my problem clearly - I'll edit it now. Thanks for pointing that out.